# Decomposing Gradient Decent Error in Eigenvector Space

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, gradient-descent, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I'm going through [Why Momentum Really Works](https://distill.pub/2017/momentum/) and am unable to understand the following line in the article.

"By writing the contributions of each eigenspace’s error to the loss
$$f(w^{k})-f(w^{\star})=\sum(1-\alpha\lambda_{i})^{2k}\lambda_{i}[x_{i}^{0}]^2$$
​​ 
we can visualize the contributions of each error component to the loss."

I am not able to figure out how the above equation was derived despite fully understanding how:

$$w^k - w^\star = Qx^k = \sum\limits_{i}^n x_i^0(1-\alpha\lambda_i)^kq_i$$

was derived and also understanding that :

$$f(w) = \frac12w^TAw-b^Tw, \quad w \in \mathbb{R}^n, A \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$$
has gradient: $$\nabla f(w) = Aw-b$$
where $A$ is symmetric and invertable and thus $f$ has optimal solution $w^\star = A^{-1}b$.
​​

I've already seen below related posts but these posts do not explain the top equation which I am trying to understand the derivation of.

[Gradient descent of $f(w)=\frac12w^TAw-b^Tw$ viewed in the space of Eigenvectors of $A$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274018/gradient-descent-of-fw-frac12wtaw-btw-viewed-in-the-space-of-eigenvectors)

[Gradient descent derivation in Eigenspace](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410758/gradient-descent-derivation-in-eigenspace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the result of a bit of tedious algebra. From the other definitions in the article, we have the following identities:
$$w^* = A^{-1}b$$
$$w^k = A^{-1}b + Qx^k$$
One identity they assume you know is that $Q^TQ = I$, which implies:
$$ Q^T A Q = Q^T Q \text{diag}[\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n]Q^T Q = \text{diag}[\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n] $$

The next steps involve writing out $f(w^k)-f(w^*)$ using the identities above and cancelling out terms. You should be able to cancel all but one term,  leaving you with the final result:
$$f(w^k) - f(w^*) = \frac{1}{2}\sum (x_i^k)^2\lambda_i = \frac{1}{2} \sum \lambda_i (1-\alpha \lambda_i)^{2k} [x_{i}^0]^2$$
I wound up off by a factor of 1/2 (I'm pretty sure the article left this factor out, since it's not that important).

---

[Edit] Tedious details are below for others who may get stuck.

We start by re-writing the loss function in terms of the quadratic and linear terms:
$$\begin{aligned}
f(w^k) - f(w^*) &= \frac{1}{2}(w^k)^TAw^k - b^T w^k \\
&\ - \frac{1}{2}(w^*)^T A w^* + b^T w^*\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\left( (w^k)^T A w^k - (w^*)^T A w^*\right) - b^T (w^k - w^*)\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\left( (w^k)^T A w^k - (w^*)^T A w^*\right) - b^TQ x^k
\end{aligned}$$
Where the last line uses the definition of $x^k$.  Now let's work out the quadratic terms separately to try and keep things managable. The quadratic term for $w^*$ is straightforward:
$$ (w^*)^T A w^* = b^T A^{-1} A A^{-1} b = b^T A^{-1} b$$
and for $w^k$ we get:
$$\begin{aligned}
(w^k)^T A w^k &=(A^{-1} b + Q x^k)^T A (A^{-1}b + Q x^k)\\
&= (A^{-1}b + Q x^k)^T(b + A Q x^k)\\
&= (b^T A^{-1} + (x^k)^T Q^T) (b + A Q x^k)\\
&= b^TA^{-1}b + b^TQ x^k + (x^k)^TQ^Tb + (x^k)^T Q^T A Q x^k\\
&= b^TA^{-1}b + 2 b^TQ x^k + (x^k)^T \text{diag}[\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n] x^k\\
&= (w^*)^T A w^* + 2 b^TQ x^k + (x^k)^T \text{diag}[\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n] x^k\\
\end{aligned}$$
and so we get
$$ \frac{1}{2} \left((w^k)^T A w^k - (w^*)^T A w^* \right) = b^T Q x^k + \frac{1}{2} (x^k)^T \text{diag}[\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n]x^k$$

Now putting this back into our expression for the loss function we have:
$$\begin{aligned}
f(w^k) - f(w^*) & = \frac{1}{2}\left( (w^k)^T A w^k - (w^*)^T A w^*\right) - b^TQ x^k\\
&= b^T Q x^k + \frac{1}{2} (x^k)^T \text{diag}[\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n]x^k - b^T Q x^k\\
&= \frac{1}{2} (x^k)^T \text{diag}[\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n]x^k\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum (x_i^k)^2\lambda_i
\end{aligned}$$